# Monitor GPS Device via Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, gps

Is it possible to monitor or trace GPS device through a Google map?
If it is possible, what are the ways to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: If you can get the GPS co-ordinates (latitude, longitude), then you can map it on a Google Map. You need to be more specific with your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. At minimum you will need the following:

1. A GPS device that has access to the internet and supports an HTTP stack for calling web services.
2. A web server that exposes web services that can be consumed by the device. These web services will allow the device to report the most recent GPS data to the server.
3. A web server (can be the same one as above for low traffic sites) that allows access to a google map rendering of the GPS data.

I have been working on a project that does this. The intent of the project is to learn how and share the experience. Here is the URL http://gpsnerd.com/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: You've told me lot of things. Thank you. If I want to know further, Is there a way to contact you?

Comment: The URL above is a site for the project. There are a bunch of links to various parts of the project on that home page. You can contact me here: http://bobcravens.com/contact

Comment: One more thing. To gain this kind of service, do I have to use all the parts(technologies & programming langs) in the above link?

Comment: @Svisstack To access the web services you need the HTTP protocol. I prefer to write application specific code instead of HTTP layer code. Thus I called out the need for an 'HTTP stack'.

Comment: @rcravens: But where in http is stack?

Comment: @Svisstack: I am simply trying to make the point that having the device (hw/sw) with a richer API that allows for easier communication with the web service (HTTP) is a good thing. Apparently, I have used the term 'stack' in a way that you don't agree with or is even technically wrong. Sorry if I wasn't clear.